One individual being served a different scrambled security certificate for our website?
We have set up a new certificate for our website using Let's Encrypt. We don't have customers using the site yet, but when we test it from multiple locations, almost everyone that goes to our site is served the correct certificate and has no problems with SSL and everything works.
However, we have one employee that gets a Not Secure error whenever he goes to our site from home. On closer inspection, when we look at the certificate in his browser, it's completely wrong and the fields look scrambled.
For example, when everyone else looks at the cert details in their browser they see the Issued To Common Name as our new URL, the Issued By Common Name as R3, and the Organization as Let's Encrypt. In his, there is no recognizable text in any field. The Organization says <Not Part of Certificate> and both the Issued To and Issued By Common Name says c1ba5fc14374.
Our site right now is hosted using IIS on an AWS server with DNS temporarily being handled by GoDaddy.
After looking through similar questions, here are some things we've tried:

We've tried multiple online certificate chain testing tools and they     all say everything looks perfect
We made sure IIS shows the correct cert and there are no other certs to choose from in IIS.
We also restarted the AWS server to make sure we cleared any caches that might be serving old certs.
We do not use any other servers such as a load balancer (other than whatever AWS or GoDaddy might use behind the scenes).
We all have the same ISP in neighboring cities, so it's doubtful it is related to his ISP.
We've waited several days for DNS and any other changes to propagate.
We tried multiple browsers on his computer with the same result
We erased all browsing data in his browsers
We tried it on his Android phone, laptop computer, and desktop computer, all with the same result, so it does not seem to be related to virus software, Windows firewall, or other device specific settings.
If he uses WIFI on his phone it does not work. However, if he uses data on his phone, it does work. (This makes us think it's related to his home network). He manages his own home network and we are not involved in any way. He says he has not done anything special with his modem or router but a service tech from the ISP might have at some point.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this or how to solve it?

The problem is clearly in his home network. We don't have any possible way to troubleshoot this. Also, it's borderline off-topic (you are seeing the problem from your business' end, but the actual issue is in a home network).

Sounds like he's got an HTTPS proxy on his network that's causing the issue.

Further to @Massimo point, the problem in his home network serves him wrong certificates. This screams security issues. Looks like possibly his home router or WiFi access point is compromised and someone really wants to get into your server from his home network (if that’s the only site he has problem with). I would not panic but tread carefully. It has all the hallmarks of a user that’s being malwared. His ISP was really his IsP who messed with the router, or a hacker pretending? You don’t know. Does your user login to that website of yours? Is he really on his WiFi or did someone spoof it?

Or his computer is compromised. Dd everyone forgot how Lenovo preinstalled Superfish on their laptops, which is doing exactly this?

Does this answer your question? How do I deal with a compromised server?

@Massimo Just to be clear about it possibly being off-topic, getting advice about servicing his home network was not our intention. This individual works from home and our concern is not so much his home network but figuring out why it's not working so we can ensure it will never happen for our customers. Our worry was that it might have been a configuration issue with the server we were overlooking. We're currently looking into his network being compromised as suggested, so thank you everyone for your advice so far.

It's looking like the issue is being caused by a content filter on his router. Now we just need to figure out why our website, which has nothing even questionably offensive on it, was immediately picked up by a content filter to block.
